# Query result based on other column

Tags: sql

I need to filter out items, not sure what is best to do it.

I need to filter out when the Overwrite is true, then it will remove when "date" and "time" has same value's record with the "Overwrite" is true from the result.

For example:
The records in the DB:

```
Date                Time          Name                 Overwrite
=======             ====        ===========            ======
10/01/2022          04:00       John White             false
11/01/2022          20:00       John Lee               false
10/01/2022          04:00       Tom Lee                true
12/01/2022          04:00       John Lee               false 

Query result want:

Date            Time        Name          Overwrite
=======         ======      ===========   ==========
10/01/2022      04:00       Tom Lee        true
11/01/2022      20:00       John Lee       false
12/01/2022      04:00       John Lee       false
```

Thanks!

Comment: Typically the `mysql` and `tsql` tags are mutually exclusive as shown in the popup tag info. Are you explicitly in need of a solution that works for both? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? "I need", even when repeated, isn't a question.

Comment: use row_number, rank or dense_rank with partition by date and tome and order the descending, this would leave all wanted rows with the number 1 which you can filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try correlated subquery using the `EXISTS Clause` as the following:

```
Select T.Date, T.Time, T.Name, T.Overwrite
From Tbl T 
Where
Not Exists (
             Select 1 From Tbl D 
             Where D.Overwrite='true' And T.Overwrite='false'
                   And D.Date=T.Date And D.Time=T.Time
           )
Order By T.Date
```

See a demo from *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=97011d2aa6687d6e377991f04242cd5c)*.

Comment: How to convert it to Power Apps

Comment: Sory, I never worked on Power Apps, but you may check this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6887/execute-sql-queries-from-microsoft-power-apps/